# Why negative number is not passed to ViewModel in caliburn micro

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have this code in VM:

```
 public void MovePixels(int NoOfPixelsToMove)
 {
            // do something with   NoOfPixelsToMove
 }
```

and on my xaml I have:

```
 <RepeatButton DockPanel.Dock="left" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[MovePixels(100)]" Content="&lt;&lt;&lt;" Margin="3" ClickMode="Press" />
 <RepeatButton DockPanel.Dock="left" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[MovePixels(10)]" Content="&lt;&lt;" Margin="3" ClickMode="Press"/>
 <RepeatButton DockPanel.Dock="left" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[MovePixels(1)]" Content="&lt;" Margin="3" ClickMode="Press"/>

 <RepeatButton DockPanel.Dock="Right" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[MovePixels(-100)]" Content=">>>" Margin="3" ClickMode="Press"/>
 <RepeatButton  DockPanel.Dock="Right" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[MovePixels(-10)]" Content=">>" Margin="3" ClickMode="Press"/>
 <RepeatButton  DockPanel.Dock="Right" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[MovePixels(-1)]" Content=">" Margin="3" ClickMode="Press"/>
```

when I click on button which should pass 100 to vm method, I am getting the value of 100 on vm method, but when I am clicking on any button which the NoOfPixelsToMove is negative, the value that passed to VM method is zero.

Why I can not passed a value which is less than zero to VM using caliburn micro?

Answer (score 1):

I think the expression does not parse it correctly. Try adding `'-'` as in `'` before the numbers.